# I don't see why Im getting this error

Tags: php, compiler-errors

I know that this is a syntax error, but I don't see what's wrong with what I did. The error is

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '{' or '$' on line 8

and the code is

```
   class Person {
    public $isAlive=true;
    public $firstname;
    public $lastname;
    public $age;
    public function __construct()
    {
    $teacher->"boring"=$firstname;
    $teacher->"12345"=$lastname;
    $teacher->12345=$age;
    $student->"Natalie Euley"=$firstname;
    $student->"Euley"=$lastname;
    $student->19=$age;
    }
    public function greet()
    {
    return "Hello, my name is ".$this->firstname." ".$this->lastname. "Nice to meet you!";
    }
    }
    $student = new Person();
    $teacher = new Person();
    echo $student->greet();
    echo $techer->greet();
```

I now understand. CodeAcademy has confusing directions. I get how to do it now. Thanks for explaining everything!

Comment: Your class member variable assignments aren't valid syntax. In fact, they're backwards. I've never seen that before.

Comment: its an impressive attempt at wrongness

Comment: @Dagon: How is that constructive? Everyone was a beginner once, and **people aren't born knowing PHP and its syntax**. I agree it is in fact a low quality question, but I personally feel such comments are rude/hurtful and has zero-relevance.

Comment: lighten up, you will live longer.

Answer (score 4):

You should be doing this:

```
$teacher->"boring" = $firstname;
```

like this:

```
$this->firstname = "boring";
```

And for the way you have the rest of your code, something like this is what you are looking for:

```
public function __construct($firstname, $lastname, $age)
{
    $this->firstname = $firstname;
    $this->lastname  = $lastname;
    $this->age       = $age;
}

$teacher = new Person("John", "Smith", 45);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is incorrect.

```
$this->firstname = "boring";
$this->lastname = "12345";
```

We use "this" if you are assigning those values to the class you are in.

It goes

```
$object->variable = value;
```

Answer (score 1):

These are wrong

```
$teacher->"boring"=$firstname;
$teacher->"12345"=$lastname;
$teacher->12345=$age;
$student->"Natalie Euley"=$firstname;
$student->"Euley"=$lastname;
$student->19=$age;
```

should be

```
$teacher->firstname = "boring";
$teacher->lastname = "12345";
$teacher->age = 12345;
$student->firstname = "Natalie Euley";
$student->lastname ="Euley";
$student->age = 19;
```

check here

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Answer (score 1):

Stuff like this:

```
$student->"Natalie Euley"=$firstname;
```

is not valid. Probably you mean

```
$student->firstname = "Natalie Euley";
```

You cannot use a `"string"` as an object key reference like that. But you could use:

```
$student->{"Natalie Euley"} = $firstname
          ^--             ^--note the brackets
```

However, this is still backwards. Assignments like that should be done `key => $value`, whereas you're doing `$value => key`, which is bass ackwards.

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax errors in your constructor method. For example is following line incorrect PHP code:

```
$student->"Natalie Euley"=$firstname;
```

I recommend to read the official documentation at http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Following improved code of you example works just fine:

```
class Person {
    public $isAlive = true;
    public $firstName;
    public $lastName;
    public $age;

    public function __construct($firstName, $lastName, $age) {
        $this->firstName = $firstName;
        $this->lastName = $lastName;
        $this->age = $age;
    }

    public function greet() {
        return 'Hello, my name is ' . $this->firstName . ' ' . $this->lastName .
            ' and I\'m '. $this->age . ' years old. Nice to meet you!';
    }
}

$student = new Person('Max', 'Kid', 19);
$teacher = new Person('Albert', 'Einstein', 60);
echo $student->greet() . "\n";
echo $teacher->greet();
```